# How can I achieve this custom ribbon group layout in Excel using xml

Tags: xml, vba, excel, customization

I'm creating a custom button group on a new ribbon group in Excel for when I distribute my VBA Macros to my company's department. To accomplish this I've been looking around the web trying to first use Button objects like [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm) until I found out that they're not the way to go when you're using later versions of Excel (I'm using 2010). So, after being pointed in the correct direction by a question on SO I've started working with `xml` and it seems pretty straightforward. I took the example from [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm) and combined it with one of the user's comments on the CustomUIEditor download page [here](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/05/26/customuieditor.aspx) and now have the below simple skeleton of `xml` code that I'll be using to create my custom tab (image is a placeholder for a different image):

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" > 
 <ribbon startFromScratch="false" > 
   <tabs> 
     <tab id="CustomTab" label="Alfred" > 
       <group id="ESPAssistant" label="ESP Assistant"> 
         <button id="Alfred" size="large" label="Alfred" imageMso="HappyFace"/> 
         <button id="Doc" label="Documentation"/> 
       </group> 
     </tab> 
   </tabs> 
 </ribbon> 
</customUI>
```

Which gives me:

[image: Current Design]

Which is so far so good. However, I'm looking to see if there is a way to have one large/medium button with an image on top and text below the image, then have the smaller button (in this case, Documentation) below the bigger button. Like so:

[image: Desired End Design]

I've been poking around the msdn documentation pages (I swear it's like playing leapfrog on those pages until you finally get to something you were truly looking for) until I found [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd926959(v=office.12).aspx), which seems to be like a plausible solution, but I couldn't seem to get that to work.

**So, my questions:**

1. Is my idea acheivable using `xml`?

   2. If so, could you help provide me with a code snippet or at least point me in the right direction of how I might accomplish this?
   3. If it's not possible, then what do you suggest I do to at least mimic something close to this layout?

Comment: I don't think so. All large Ribbon buttons I've seen take up an entire "spot", there's never anything under a large Ribbon button. IMO your design would clash with the Microsoft designs if you got it to work.

Comment: I figured as much. What would you suggest then for something similar?

Comment: Not much, other than add an icon to your "documentation" button ;-)

Comment: Haha I don't want the "documentation" button to be the same size as the "Alfred" button. If anything, I'd prefer it move to the button to align with the word "Alfred", then I'd like to add the icon to it. Any idea how I could do *that*?

Comment: Use a vertical divider or a split button drop down with menu separators. Or just make a small icon. Or insert a large transparent image.

Comment: Vertical divider doesn't help and I rather not use a split butter drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is in fact not possible to accomplish as this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316927(v=vs.85).aspx) points out that the [ScalingPolicy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316839(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SizeDefinitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316846(v=vs.85).aspx) enforced by Excel's framework do not allow non-uniformity, even when using their UI Customization. Sigh.